# I can't get my localhost website to go public on the internet (using Xampp and no-ip.com)

Tags: xampp, dynamic-dns

I am trying to host a website locally on my PC and publish it on the internet. I am using `no-ip.com` and I created a dns host called (for example) `mydnshostname.ddns.com`.

I altered my `drivers/etc/hosts` file and now when I hit `localhost` it goes directly to my site.

I also altered my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file on the apache and included this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/mydnshostname"
    ServerName mydnshostname.ddns.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I hit `mydnshostname.ddns.com` (from my computer) I get my website correctly.

But when I try to hit it from another PC I get server not found.

If the other PC is on another network then I can't find the website at all (of course)

If the other PC is on *my* network I can find it under `192.168.1.x` (the ip of my desktop where I host it) but *not* when I hit `mydnshostname.ddns.com`.

Is there a setting that I'm missing? How can I publish it online?

Comment: you need to redirect incomming http (por 80) traffic to your PC 192.168.1.X. This is usually done in your modem/router.

Comment: and you will need 443 tcp if your doing SSL aka https webserver.

Answer (score 0):

As for your other computer on the same network, you'll need to edit the 'hosts' file for name resolution...or set up your own internal DNS server, and point all of your PC's on that network to use the DNS server.

Sometimes routers have some DNS functionality...but the quickest way for local testing is just to make an entry in the /etc/hosts file.  Assuming you have windows as your desktop, just do a search for how to edit the /etc/hosts file in windows (it can be done).

Archemar's comment is correct, you'll need to do port forwarding (via your router) for all incoming traffic on port 80 to be directed to the PC that you have running Apache.

Lastly, depending on your hosting OS, you will need to adjust your firewall settings on your webserver PC -- to allow in-coming the connections on 80.

Comment: The other thing you want to check is if your ISP allows for you to have your own web server out of your house (assuming you have a residential connection).

Comment: thanks! I ll try port forwarding tomorrow. I hope the isp allows it. as for my OS I have windows 7 here. I dont use any firewall other than the one from windows.